# Access violation reading location 0xcccccd84

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error

I'm new to c++ currently working on my assignment and encounter this runtime error "Access violation reading location" when trying to assign iterator pointer into array using for loop.

```
Flist = data.getFList();

for(Fit = Flist.begin(); Fit != Flist.end(); Fit++)
{
   ++counter;
   cout << "(" << counter << ") Destination: " << Fit->getDest() << " [Class: " ><< Fit->getClass() << "]" << endl;

    _getch();
    fArr[counter] = *Fit;
}
```

### Constructor

```
Staff::Staff()
{
    counter = 0;
    fArr = new Flight[counter];
};
```

### Header

```
Flight *fArr;
int counter;
```

Any help will be great~

Comment: The "constructor", as you posted it now, doesn't do anything sensible : `fArr=new Flight[0];`?!

Comment: Learn to use your debugger. And enable all warnings and debugging information at compilation time.

Comment: @us2012 you're right, maybe I've misunderstanding the use of new keyword =] thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you allocate memory in the constructor, you're creating an array of `0` size, that doesn't really make sense.

Instead, just use a vector of flights: `std::vector<Flight> fArr`, and push back to it:

```
fArr.push_back(*Fit);
```

Comment: Ahh.. I thought the "new" is used to dynamically change the size of Flight array in runtime cause I'm using the same method for memcpy it works.

Comment: You can use `new` to dynamically allocate some number of Flight objects, but that memory doesn't automatically resize. Vector takes car of doing that for you behind the scenes.